# Unity search doesn't find all files (16.04 LTS)

Tags: unity, libreoffice, unity-dash, search

Why does Dash fail in finding files sometimes? I'm getting annoyed by this. First it was freshly installed apps, now it literally does not allocate the file next to the one it finds.

If you look at the photo, notice that after searching "luka", the document finds "luka_perfect", but now "luka", also a libreoffice document (right in Documents).

[image: Unity Dash doesn't find file]

And that's not the first instance of that. 
Anyone know why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you are looking for, however, you can run the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences enable-interactive-search false
```

Now, you should be able to open Nautilus or Files and you will be able to search the current directory recursively just by typing stuff.

So if you were to type "luka" with the file manager open, all results will display.